# How to use data and auto-input it into a website text box?

Tags: database, post, input, authentication

I have login credentials in a database and would like to post them into a text box. Gmail for example the login page is:

https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1

I want to post the email info into Email input box and the password in the Passwd box.

I do not want to post the data through php. I looked at cURL but I do not think it does the job. What would you recommend for doing a task like this.

```
<?php
$val = "SomeData";
?>
```

On a different page not on my site

```
<input id="email" name="email" value="" type="text"></input>
```

How would I put $val in the input box on a different site?

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to authenticate against google with your account, or the accounts of your users,  a better approach would be to use openid or oauth rather than trying to pass plain text usernames and passwords around in the browser - not that what you are suggesting would actually be possible anyway as far as I am aware.

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

Glen

Comment: I want to be able to log in to any website not just gmail. I'm trying to find something more in the range of inserted the data into autocomplete.

Comment: In that case what you are trying to do is not possible as far as I am aware - the only way you could do it via a web page is if you could use javascript from an iframe to update form fields in another frame - but you can't do this if the source of your iframes is from different hosts - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript